# Fatal Exception OkHttp Dispatcher with RetroFit

Tags: java, android, retrofit, okhttp

I am using RetroFit to make a call to [TheMovieDatabase API](https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/movies/get-popular-movies) and am trying to get a list of the popular movies to populate into a `RecylerView`. However, when I make the call through RetroFit, I am getting an error related to OkHTTP. I am using OkHTTP in conjunction with RetroFit:

```
06-08 19:57:26.281 19232-19254/popularmovies.troychuinard.com.popularmovies E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
    Process: popularmovies.troychuinard.com.popularmovies, PID: 19232
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lokhttp3/internal/Platform;
        at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor$Logger$1.log(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:112)
        at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:160)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200)
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147)
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "okhttp3.internal.Platform" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/popularmovies.troychuinard.com.popularmovies-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/popularmovies.troychuinard.com.popularmovies-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/popularmovies.troychuinard.com.popularmovies-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/popularmovies.troychuinard.com.popularmovies-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/popularmovies.troychuinard.com.popularmovies-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/popularmovies.troychuinard.com.popularmovies-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/popularmovies.troychuinard.com.popularmovies-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/popularmovies.troychuinard.com.popularmovies-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/popularmovies.troychuinard.com.popularmovies-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/popularmovies.troychuinard.com.popularmovies-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/popularmovies.troychuinard.com.popularmovies-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/popularmovies.troychuinard.com.popularmovies-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/popularmovies.troychuinard.com.popularmovies-2/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor$Logger$1.log(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:112) 
        at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:160) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
        at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200) 
        at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:147) 
        at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Below is my relevant code from RetroFit:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(i), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            String selection = String.valueOf(i);
            switch (i){
                case 0:
                    query = "popular";
                    mBaseURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular/";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    query = "top_rated";
                    mBaseURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated/";
                    break;
                default:
                    query = "popular";
                    mBaseURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular/";
                    break;
            }
            mMovieURLS.clear();
            mMovieResultsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
            interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient
                    .Builder()
                    .addInterceptor(interceptor)
                    .build();

            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(mBaseURL)
                    .client(client)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            ApiInterface apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);
            Call<TheMovieDatabase> call = apiInterface.getImages();
            call.enqueue(new Callback<TheMovieDatabase>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<TheMovieDatabase> call, Response<TheMovieDatabase> response) {
                    String movieResponse = String.valueOf(response.isSuccessful());
                    Log.v("SUCESS", movieResponse);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<TheMovieDatabase> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
        }
```

API InterFace:

```
    public interface ApiInterface{
    @GET("?api_key=xxxxxxxxx&language=en-US")
    Call<TheMovieDatabase> getImages();
}
```

Gradle Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.0'
}
```

Comment: share your gradle dependencies of retrofit, okhttp & http-interceptor.

Comment: thanks, just shared the Gradle dependencies

Comment: Very odd, I changed my dependencies to lower versions of RetroFit and it was able to work, I feel RetroFit may need to address

Comment: Actually, the crash says that `okhttp3.internal.Platform` file was not found in any of the dex file. This is because you're using two different versions of okhttp library here `com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.3.0` and `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0`. I would recommend you to update the version of `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0` instead of downgrading Retrofit.

Comment: So I have the latest okhttp, you are saying downgrade it to match the same version as the logging interceptor?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question has been 2 years, but I solve mine. So here is an alternate answer you could try.

My error started after upgrading version of my dependencies(Android Studio suggested it after looking in project structure). Since the problem involve Retrofit and OkHttp, I revert back to the older version that I use, when my app was working. So, I suggest to revert back to older version of :

```
 implementation  'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:*older version here*'
 implementation  'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:*older version here*'
 implementation  'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:*older version here*'
 implementation  'oauth.signpost:oauth-signpost:*older version here*'
 implementation  'se.akerfeldt:okhttp-signpost:*older version here*'
 implementation  'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:*older version here*'
 implementation  'oauth.signpost:signpost-core:*older version here*'
```

That is the dependencies that I revert back to older version. I suggest you change any Retrofit or OkHttp related dependencies back to older version when your app was working.

If you have any problem figuring out what is the older version that is available, I suggest to look into dependencies version from *Project Structure* > *Dependencies* tab > *app* tab. from there you can find your dependencies that you are looking for, and change the version.

Good luck